# Sql Trigger After Insert Update another table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am creating After Insert trigger , its working fine, but I have certain conditions before executing the statements inside the trigger

> 1. Based on Different CustomerId Run the trigger, I want check which CustomerId got inserted in my LoyaltyDetailsTable, say if last insert
>      was Customerid=2 then pass that Customerid in where condition then run
>      the trigger , or if Customerid = 1 then run the trigger for that Id,
>      so on.
> 2. I want to check whether in PriceClaimTable the inserted CustomerId exist  or not, If exists then update the details else just insert the
>      values in LoyaltyDetailsTable only.

**Trigger query**

```
CREATE TRIGGER DetailsAfterInsert ON [dbo].[LoyaltyDetailsTable]
FOR INSERT

as

UPDATE PriceClaimTable 
SET CurrentPoints = 
(  
(SELECT SUM(LoayaltyPointsTable.Points) AS RecentPoints FROM LoayaltyPointsTable
join LoyaltyDetailsTable ON LoayaltyPointsTable.LoyaltyPointsId 
= LoyaltyDetailsTable.LoyaltyPointsId
WHERE CustomerId=1 and LoyaltyDetailsId= (SELECT MAX(LoyaltyDetailsId)  
AS LoyaltyDetailsTable FROM LoyaltyDetailsTable))

+ 

(SELECT CurrentPoints FROM PriceClaimTable WHERE ClaimCustomerId=1 and 
PriceClaimId=(SELECT max(PriceClaimId) FROM PriceClaimTable
))

) 
WHERE ClaimCustomerId=1 and PriceClaimId=(SELECT max(PriceClaimId) FROM PriceClaimTable)
```

This is my first attempt to write a trigger, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432383/linq-update-a-row-if-new-rows-are-inserted-in-another-table) is table structure.

Any help would be great.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: Two things. First your trigger is not referencing the inserted virtual table. Second, this seems like a computed column would make a lot more sense than a trigger. You will never have accurate data when you try to maintain a balance like this. At some point it will get out of synch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for here is the `inserted` table. Every time you issue an `UPDATE` statement, SQL Server generates two virtual tables called `inserted` and `deleted` that store information on the data modifications you're making. These tables are accessible from your trigger. For more information, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

You can use `inserted` to get the IDs you're looking for. So, instead of:

```
WHERE ClaimCustomerId=1
```

you can use:

```
WHERE ClaimCustomerId=inserted.ClaimCustomerId
```

Comment: hi, that was good idea, from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404219/sql-server-trigger-on-insert-and-how-to-reference-the-data-that-was-inserted), i changed to WHERE CustomerId=(select CustomerId from INSERTED ) , but i get error as'Invalid object name 'INSERTED'.'

Comment: Thank you so much, for guiding me, as you said i was looking for that one word 'inserted', and that made the solution,  the error :'Invalid object name 'INSERTED'.' was resolved when i came to know that inserted runs only when insert happens in a table. i managed to execute all correctly, sometimes your one word trains us here in stackoverflow, so dont stop answering if you have just small words which can be turned  into solutions. Appreciate your effort.